# Makefile: use multiple makefiles

Tags: makefile

I have a project that has many makefiles inside it. Because sometimes I need to compile only some parts of my project so I decided to have one makefile in each directory. But when I want to run the main makefile that includes all other ones to compile my project it gives me lots of errors.
This is my project tree:

root 'makefile'

-folder1 'foo1.c foo2.c makefile'

-folder2 'makefile'

--folder2-1 'foo3.c foo4.c makefile'

--folder2-2 'foo5.c makefile'

Each makefile in the very last directory has been included to it's upper makefile. But it doesn't run the main makefile. I'm really new to GNU make and I want to have something like this but I don't know how. I just wrote some make scripts but it doesn't work.
I just want to have something that I can compile the projects parts separately or compile the whole project using multiple makefiles.

Comment: you can use `-C` option in TOP `makefile` to compile each directory

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: You mentioned lots of errors, but you never said what they were or provided any part of your makefile. For each folder, you want to use `$(MAKE) -C folder_name` as @How mentioned. Also, are you sure that you are using the correct format? Any targets to make should appear in the first column while the rules to actually make those targets should be indented by one tab character (not spaces; your editor may be using spaces even though you hit the tab key).

Comment: Thank you. make -C DIRECTORY solved my problem. I thought that if I include the sub makefiles and call the targets, it will compile them. But it's wrong. I used -C and now it's working. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

any way, I show you something and hope can help you:

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -C subfolder
```

or if you want to use *.mk as your sub makefile, you can write:

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -C busfolder -f somename.mk
```

I show you my example, my DIR looks like:

```
TOPDIR-- Makefile
|
|-- debug
|   |-- debug.c
|   |-- debug.h
|   |-- debug.mk
|   |-- instrument.c
|   `-- uart_print.c
|-- driver
|   |-- driver.c
|   |-- driver_ddi.c
|   |-- driver_ddi.h
|   |-- driver.h
|   `-- driver.mk
|-- include
|   `-- common.h
|-- Makefile
|-- mw
|   |-- manager.c
|   `-- mw.mk
|-- root
|   |-- main.c
|   `-- root.mk
```

and my TOP makefile looks like:

```
MAKE_DIR = $(PWD)

ROOT_DIR    := $(MAKE_DIR)/root 
DRV_DIR     := $(MAKE_DIR)/driver
INCLUDE_DIR := $(MAKE_DIR)/include
DEBUG_DIR   := $(MAKE_DIR)/debug

INC_SRCH_PATH := 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(ROOT_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DRV_DIR) 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DEBUG_DIR)

LIB_SRCH_PATH :=
LIB_SRCH_PATH += -L$(MAKE_DIR)/libs


COLOR_ON = color
COLOR_OFF = 
CC = $(COLOR_ON)gcc
#CC = $(COLOR_OFF)gcc
LD = ld

LINT = splint

LIBS := -ldriver -ldebug -lmw -lm -lpthread

CFLAGS :=
CFLAGS += $(INC_SRCH_PATH) $(LIB_SRCH_PATH) 
CFLAGS += -Wall -O -ggdb -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-pointer-sign -finstrument-functions -fdump-rtl-expand
CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -D_REENTRANT

LDFLAGS :=

export MAKE_DIR CC LD CFLAGS LDFLAGS LIBS LINT INC_SRCH_PATH

all:
    @$(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C driver -f driver.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C mw -f mw.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C driver -f driver.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C mw -f mw.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk clean
```

it will call sub DIR *.mk during the compile. The sub DIR makefile, I just write a simple example for you reference:

```
LIB = $(MAKE_DIR)/libs/yourmodulename.a
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p ../libs
    @$(AR) cr $@ $^
    @echo "    Archive    $(notdir $@)"

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
    @echo "    CC        $(OBJS)"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(LIB) $(OBJS)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
```

for the makefile, which generate the final target file(like a.out) is little bit different, because I use the sub makefile to generate LIB file, and I use a root.mk to generate final target:

```
PROG = ../prog/DEMO

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

$(PROG): $(SRCS)
    @mkdir -p ../prog
    @$(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-Map=$(PROG).map $(LIBS) -o $@
    @echo "    Generate Program $(notdir $(PROG)) from $^"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(PROG)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @$(RM) -rf ../prog ../libs
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
    @echo "    Remove Libraries:  $(notdir $(PROG))"
```